# re a 2 row treble diatonic button accordion

Tags: instruments

I am used to playing a 2 row treble BC button accordion with the B row on the inside & the C row on the outside. I now have a new Castagnari similar one, but the 2 treble rows are the opposite to what I am used to, with the C row on the inside. Is it possible to swap them around?? Thanks. Mills.